# CSS div problems with position

Tags: asp.net, css, html, master-pages

I have a css based asp.net masterpage.  I am using a browse div located directly above a navigation div.  The browse div is flowing down behind the navigation div.  I did some playing around with the position and found that if i change the navigation position it fixes it, but everything in that div moves half way down the page.  I have done some googleing and cant find anything about how to force a div to always be on top.  If you need more info I can provide it.

I have pasted select parts of the css code below:

```
#header2 {
height: 2.5em;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #0055a5;
color: #FFF;
background-color: white;
}

#header2 .browse {
color: #000000;
background-color: transparent;
float: left;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-top: .1em;
font-weight:bold;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-size: 70%;
line-height: normal;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
width: 144px;
position: fixed;    
}

#navigation 
{
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
height:100%;
top: 105px;
left: 0em;
width: 13em;    
position: absolute;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
}
```

Comment: There part that is falling behind the navigation is a javascript menu drop down.

Comment: Please include a simplified version of the markup for these. There is important info there as to who is nested where. Also, please give a link to a sample page. thanks

Comment: I cant provide links to sample pages.  These pages are meant for intranet only.  Thanks for you concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By top, do you mean the top of the viewport, or top of the stack (i.e., z-index?).

If you mean top of the viewport, try position:fixed;

Edit, reading again, I think you mean z-index. Set the position of the element you want to keep on top (browse?) to relative, and then set the z-index to something like 100, i.e.,

```
position:relative;z-index:100;
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stay fixed at the very top of the page, you could try setting `top: 0;` on the `.browse` class. Also see if it is the actual `<div>` tag that it is positioned vertically centered, or if it's just its contents.

I bet you'll save some time experimenting if you use [firebug](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firebug/addon/1843) - go get it if you don't have it already =)